# Need help printing a string with a delimiter (python)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to repeat a string with a delimiter. However, I cannot figure out how to stop the delimiter from being the final thing printed.

Here's my code:

```
userString = "Ted"
repetition = int(10)
separator = " + "

for i in range(repetition):
        print(userString, separator,  end = '')
```

Here's my output:

```
Ted  + Ted  + Ted  + Ted  + Ted  + Ted  + Ted  + Ted  + Ted  + Ted  +
```

As you can see, the delimiter is the last thing to print, but I want 'Ted' to be the last thing printed.

Edit:
Thank you for the help. I ended up cutting my loop short by 1 and printing userString again at the end. My professor wants me to refrain from .join and like methods as we haven't learned them yet.

Comment: What keeps you from stopping your loop one iteration sooner and then printing the last `Ted`?

Comment: you are looking for `seperator.join`

Comment: or maybe the `sep` argument to `print`?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to solve this problem. Here's one:

```
separator.join([userString] * repetition)
#'Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted'
```

Here's another:

```
(userString + separator) * (repetition - 1) + userString
#'Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted'
```

And one more:

```
print(*([userString] * repetition), sep=separator)
#Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted + Ted
```